# Laravel / League Fractal returns an empty array instead of empty object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, thephpleague-fractal

I'm having a problem with Fractal library. I'm using Spatie\laravel-fractal library which is just wrapper for League\fractal. So...

I want to return an empty object instead of an empty array.

```php
public function includeDocumentType(Question $question)
{
    return $question->documentType
        ? $this->item($question->documentType, new DocumentTypeTransformer)
        : $this->null();
}
```

`$this->null()` always returns `[]` after generation and I want to return `{}`. Tbh I want to have 2 functions like `$this->nullItem()` and `$this->nullCollection()`.

Does anyone know what's the solution to this problem?

Comment: Instead of `$this->null()` you could just return `new stdClass()` (for the empty object)

Comment: @ljubadr It won't work as this function is expected to return `League\Fractal\Resource\ResourceInterface`

Comment: Does `$this->item(null, new DocumentTypeTransformer)` work?

Comment: Or you could return a `NullResource`, perhaps? https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal/blob/master/src/Resource/NullResource.php https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal/issues/124

Comment: @ceejayoz The problem is `new NullResource()` is always converted to an array. I have created an issue on their library GitHub page. Hopefully, they will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem. I wanted to return empty array instead of `NullResource`. Here is what I was able to find from the source code.

Instead of `$this->null()`, `$this->primitive(null)` did the trick. You can enter whatever you want to be returned.

In your case `$this->primitive(new \stdClass())` should be the way to go.

[image]